# Fundamental solutions of differential operator $\left(1-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^p$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good evening everyone,
I have a question about fundamental solution of the operator
$$\left(1-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^p.$$
I have read that its fundamental solution G verifies: $$G \in \mathcal{C}^{2p-2}$$ and with integrable derivatives of order less or equal to $2p-2$. 
I want to know, how can I show this? Or if there is a book or article which explain this with a rigorous proof.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is the domain/boundary conditions?

Comment: a fundamental solution G of the operator $$L$$ is the solution of the inhomogeneous equation

$$LG = \delta $$ .
where  $$\delta $$ is Dirac delta and G is a priori only assumed to be a distribution